# Iterate through FOR CURSOR in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, db2

I just started with coding in Python and I have one problem. I am using ibm_dbi driver.

Here is my sql example:

```
    FOR v AS cur CURSOR FOR
       SELECT S.NAME FROM SYSIBM.SYSTABLES AS S
       JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT TBNAME FROM SYSIBM.SYSCOLUMNS WHERE CREATOR = 'SOME_SCHEMA_DB') AS C.TBNAME = S.NAME WHERE S.CREATOR = 'SOME_SCHEMA' AND S.TYPE = 'T'
       DO
         SET TABLE = SCHEMA1 ||'.'||v.Name
         ...
         SELECT 1 INTO TEMP_TABLE FROM SYSIBM.SYSTABLES WHERE TYPE='T' AND CREATOR = SCHEMA1 AND NAME = v.NAME
    END FOR;
```

So far i have in Python:

```
#make a connection to db
conn = ibm_db_dbi.connect("DATABASE=%s;HOSTNAME=%s,....)
#define a cursor
cur = conn.cursor()
sql="""SELECT S.NAME FROM SYSIBM.SYSTABLES AS S
           JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT TBNAME FROM SYSIBM.SYSCOLUMNS WHERE CREATOR = 'SOME_SCHEMA_DB') AS C.TBNAME = S.NAME WHERE S.CREATOR = 'SOME_SCHEMA' AND S.TYPE = 'T'"""

resultSet = cur.execute(sql)
```

I don't know how to iterate through result from query and set values from the cursor. How to set value for this piece of code

```
SET TABLE = SCHEMA1 ||'.'||v.Name
             ...
SELECT 1 INTO TEMP_TABLE FROM SYSIBM.SYSTABLES WHERE TYPE='T' AND CREATOR = SCHEMA1 AND NAME = v.NAME
```

Comment: That looks like SQL and not Python. Where is your Python code?

Comment: Yes this is sql code and i want this to write to python. I already have a connection to db and i know how to put this query in variable, for example sql and execute the sql ( cursor.execute(sql) ). How to create this for cursor statement and set values dynamic for each table in some schema?

Comment: Share your Python code you have so far, try some iteration and if you run into an issue, post the error here. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice

Comment: Don't use cursors

Comment: Why not cursors? Do you have any other solution? Idea is to iterate through all tables in some schema and after that go through all attributes of those tables

Answer (score 0):

Tip: get your SQL working outside of python first. Your question shows that query that has syntax mistakes or typos.

To iterate through a result-set from a query, use one of the documented fetch methods for the DBI interface (example, `fetchmany()` , or `fetchall()` or others).

Here is a fragment, that uses fetchmany() .

```
try:
   cur = conn.cursor()
   sql="""SELECT S.NAME FROM SYSIBM.SYSTABLES AS S
          inner JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT TBNAME 
                      FROM SYSIBM.SYSCOLUMNS 
                      WHERE TBCREATOR = 'SOME_SCHEMA') AS C
          ON C.TBNAME = S.NAME 
          WHERE S.CREATOR = 'SOME_SCHEMA' 
          AND S.TYPE = 'T';"""
   cur.execute(sql)
   result = cur.fetchmany()
   while result:
       for i in result:
           print(i)
       result = cur.fetchmany()


except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    raise
```